# Statistics on the usage of virtual block devices in Xen

Tags: virtualization, xen, diskimage

There are typically three types of virtual block devices supported by virtualization environments such as Xen. They are, file based disk images, logical volume manager(LVM) based disk spaces, and physical partitions. I know that file base disk image is the easiest to set up and physical partition is the fastest in io and LVM is the most suitable when expanding. But does anyone know in average wot percentage of people use file base disk images, LVM and physical partitions in vritualization enviornment? Any site which will have this kind of information??

Answer (score 0):

I can't give you a specific site, however most people use LVM.  I am more familiar with the XenServer side of things, but with that software package, the default type of storage is LVM.  Infact, most of the XenServer community goes with LVM unless they need partition based (ext3) storage for the intellicache feature.

Another thing you should consider is that you are talking about "virtualization environments", however most people use shared network storage.  Then the question changes to "NFS or iSCSI?"